# Which visualization Tool Suits my project

Tags: opencv, opengl, graphics, 3d

I am doing a project on container loading. There are some boxes which has to be filled into container. The location and position of the box in the container is known. I need to vuisualize these boxes in 3d. can any one suggest me which tool suits for the problem.

Answer (score -1):

a simple synoptic with boxes containing boxes is quiet straight forward for an opengl programmer. the easiest library is surely [opentk](http://www.opentk.com/), it's portable and c# is one of the easiest language

[image: simple opentk example]